# What's the "$it" in a shell command?

Tags: shell

```
> sys | get host.users | echo $it
```

It's from the [introduction page](https://book.nushell.sh/en/introduction) of the [Nu Shell](https://github.com/nushell/nushell).
I've already known something like "$.." is a variable in shell, but I can't find any definition before using.
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZ1fb.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [repo](https://github.com/nushell/nushell#opening-files): `...$it to refer to the value being piped to the external command.`

So, in order to use commands outside of Nu once you have the data you want, `$it` refers to the value you wanna pipe to the external command.

In your example it is explained:

> If this looks very similar to what we had before, you have a keen eye!
>   It is similar, but with one important difference: we've called echo
>   with the value we saw earlier. This allows us to pass data out of Nu
>   into echo (or any command outside of Nu, like git for example)